# Convergence of the SARSA algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, convergence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, sarsa

I'm trying to figure out the convergence of the SARSA algorithm, but I need help. In the article "On the Convergence of Stochastic Iterative Dynamic Programming" by Jakkola, Jordana and Singh (1993), the following convergence conditions are given:

1. the limitation of sets of states and actions
2. Limited variance of rewards for actions
3. The learning rate parameter (alpha) is such that the sum of a series of alphas diverges, and a sum of alpha squares converges

[image]

And here is a misunderstanding with the third condition: in many examples, alpha is taken constant, but then the sum of squares will disperse. Why can I take alpha constant? Will the value function then converge to the optimal one?

Comment: oh this is a much more general phenomenon of stochastic optimization, rather than a property of SARSA. We have theory which says our learning rates have to be a certain way, and in practice, we ignore this, as different things seem to actually do better. (this type of optimization theory tends to be extremely pessimistic, and empirical progress for a given executed optimization algorithm is far beyond the progress guaranteed by the theory in many cases).